This code changes the style of a targeted element in the console debug but does not change it in the DOM
let html
function display(array){
    tasksList.innerHTML = ''
    html = ''
    array.forEach(elm=>{

        html += `<li>

        <span id="${elm.id}" class="${elm.class}">${elm.title}</span>

        <p >${elm.desc}</p>
                <div>
                <button id="${elm.id}" class="done-task">Done</button>
                <button id="${elm.id}" class="delete-task">Delete</button>
                <button id="${elm.id}" class="edit-task">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </li>`

            tasksList.innerHTML = html
    })
}

tasksList.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{

    if(e.target.tagName == 'SPAN'){
        console.log(e.target.nextElementSibling.tagName)

            e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('desc')
            e.target.style.color = 'red'

    console.log('Changed color to red for', e.target.nextElementSibling);
    }
})


this is the only css related to that part:
  #tasks-list li span{
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  /* #tasks-list li p{
     display: none;
  } */

  .desc{
     display: none;
  }

in the console it states that the nextElementSibling is actually adding the class and the style but in the same time in the DOM it doesn't.
I have tried adding the class manually to the  and it did hide the element.
I tried console logging the targetElement and to console log its sibling and indeed they both return to be the span and the p.

Can you update the question to include a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe?

I was preparing the code snippet and the code just works as intended. I have spent the whole afternoon wondering what is happening!
I have tried the code both in edge and chrome and it's not working but in codepen it just works.
I wonder why!

The issue is likely how the innerHTML updates are happening during the forEach loop. Each iteration overwrites the entire content, which can interfere with event listeners and DOM state. Try this fix:
let html = '';

function display(array) {
    // Build HTML string once
    html = array.map(elm => `
        <li>
            <span id="${elm.id}" class="${elm.class}">${elm.title}</span>
            <p>${elm.desc}</p>
            <div>
                <button id="${elm.id}" class="done-task">Done</button>
                <button id="${elm.id}" class="delete-task">Delete</button>
                <button id="${elm.id}" class="edit-task">Edit</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    `).join('');
    
    // Update DOM once
    tasksList.innerHTML = html;
}

tasksList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
        const desc = e.target.nextElementSibling;
        desc.classList.toggle('desc');
        e.target.style.color = 'red';
    }
});

I used array.map() instead of forEach to build HTML and moved innerHTML update outside the loop. Also simplified event listener logic
This should resolve the issues you're experiencing.

unfortunately it didn't update in the browsers neither.
